# chrome "aw, snap" crash, but can't see crash log in chrome://crashes but see DMP generated, so what is the quickest way to interpret this DMP file

Tags: google-chrome, dmp

I can see my page get crash(see aw, snap page) with 20% proprobility after 10 mins(otherwise it runs well like forever)

so I tried:

1) CPU and memory check with task manager, and see no increasing(so no leakage).

2) enable crush log in the chrome://settings/
result:

2.1) see still nothing in the chrome://crashes page, not even a crush ID (0 crashes).

2.2) see nothing in the folder under path

```
C:/%User%/AppData/Local/Google/CrashReports (nothing in) nor 

C:/%User%/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Crash Reports (folder not exist)
```

2.3) but indeed see DMP in the:

```
C:/%User%/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/CrashPads/reports
```

but seems they are not readable, and it also seems not the correct address for crash logs

3) can get chrome log either by command line arguments, or using sawbuck, but found nothing but only 2 errors, one for sawbuck itself, and another saying can't send the report to google.

So the questions are:

1) are those DMP the crash logs(the default Dir for dump file has been changed for chrome v50)

2) how can I abstract information out of the DMP file, if chrome://crashes page shows nothing (for chrome on windows)
p.s. 2 usage pages are found at https://www.chromium.org/developers/decoding-crash-dumps
https://www.chromium.org/developers/crash-reports

but seems it's not for windows without a recompile of chrome's component, is there any 3rd party tools to interpret the DMP file?

**env informations:**

```
chrome version: 50.0.2661.02 m
; Host OS: windows 10
```

Comment: dmp files under C:/%User%/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/CrashPads/reports could be decoded using windbg where crashing reason will be listed, and with symbols loaded from symbol server it can also provide call stack.

Answer (score 0):

The crash dumps (`.dmp` files) in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Crashpad\reports` can be read by standard Windows debuggers. WinDbg is one tool (provided by Microsoft) for analysing these dumps; it's not going to win any beauty contents, but it's powerful and gets the job done. The recommended way to obtain it is, somewhat bizarrely, the [Windows Driver Kit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx).

You'll need debugging symbols to make sense of the results, and these aren't included in standard builds of Chrome. To get symbols for both Chrome and the Windows runtime, set the following as your Symbols path:

```
    SRV*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;SRV*c:\symbols*https://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com
```

There are numerous resources on using WinDbg on the web; [this cheat sheet](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html) contains some useful commands to get you started.